# How to solve [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable using uwsgi + nginx

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi with this configuration :

> net.core.somaxconn = 1024
>
> net.core.netdev_max_backlog=1000

I got **resource temporarily unavailable** issue. How to resolve this issue?

> df -h
>   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/xvda1
>
> 7.8G  2.1G  5.6G  28% / devtmpfs
>
> 1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev tmpfs
>
> 1.9G   16K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm

Answer (score 0):

You can increase 'listen' value in uwsgi configure file. 
The default value is 100 which is too small.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this issue here: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1266